# Use Milne Thomson circle theorem to show complex potential for this flow

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, fluid-dynamics

I was wondering if anyone could help me with the following problem, as I'm unsure on how to begin. Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks for reading this.

I just don't understand how to apply this with the [Milne Thomson theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milne-Thomson_circle_theorem) to get the required result.

I know that the complex potential for a line vortex is $w(z)=-iΓ/2\pi \ln()$

Here is an image of the question: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUNDD.jpg)

Two equal line vortices of circulation $\Gamma$ lie at coordinates $x= - 2a, y = 0$ and $x=2a, y=0$ and are situated near a rigid circular cylinder of radius $a$, given by the equation $x^2 + y^2 = a^2$.

Using the Milne-Thomson circle theorem, show that the complex potential for this flow is
$$\omega (z) = - \frac{i\Gamma}{2\pi} \left[ \ln (z-2a) - \ln \left(\frac{a^2} z - 2a\right) + \ln (z + 2a) - \ln \left( \frac{a^2} z + 2a \right) \right]$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the vortex at $z=2a$ (without the cylinder), you have
$$w(z) = \frac{-i\Gamma}{2\pi}\log(z-2a).$$
We use the circle theorem to account for the cylinder and so compute the new potential $w_2$:
$$w_2(z) = \frac{-i\Gamma}{2\pi}\log(z-2a) + \frac{i\Gamma}{2\pi}\log\left(\frac{a^2}{z} - 2a\right),$$
where the second term in $w_2$ is, of course, $\overline{w\left(\frac{a^2}{\overline{z}}\right)}$.

For the vortex at $z=-2a$, you do the same thing. Combining these two and factoring out $\frac{-i\Gamma}{2\pi}$ will give what you want.

Comment: Thank you! How would I find stagnation points and minimum pressure points at the surface of the cylinder?

Comment: @Sam To find the stagnation points, you can find the zeros of $w_2^\prime$. Bernoulli's equation should help you out with minimum pressure at the surface of the cylinder.

Comment: @GaryMoon, maybe I'm missing something but in my textbook by Batchelor the Milne Thomson theorem is presented as $w_{2}(z)=w(z)+\overline{w\left(\frac{a^2}{z}\right)}$ not $\overline{w\left(\frac{a^2}{\overline{z}}\right)}$. Is there a difference?

Comment: @WnGatRC456 There isn't a difference. In the above, the first term in $w_2$ is $w$, it's just not denoted $w$.